# How can I upload an hierarchy of folders (and files) in an app-hosted document library in a Sharepoint hosted app project?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a Sharepoint hosted app project (using Sharepoint 2013). I want the users who use the app to be able to upload directly a folder (containing at least one file and one subfolder with at least 10 files) in the app-hosted document library there is.

My problems are:

1. Drag and drop allows only files.
2. The sync button in the app-hosted document library doesn't work neither in IE nor in Chrome.
3. Only in IE, when I click 'Upload Document', there is a link in order to "Upload files using Windows Explorer instead" but it doesn't work. Windows Explorer's window doesn't even open.

Finally, I'm using Javascript in my project and Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.

Thank you all very much in advance!